# Getting Values from SELECT in ASP.NET codebehind

Tags: c#, asp.net, forms

I have the following content:

```
<input type="text" name="val1">
<select name="sel1"><option value="1">one</option><option value="2">two</option></select>
```

When iterating the formdata using

```
Request.Form.Allkeys
```

Both values (val1 and sel1) are inside the keys-List, but while Form["val1"] has the content I entered in the form, Form["sel1"] is always null.

(Using server-controls is not an option in this case)

Comment: You need to give values to each `<option>`

Comment: You must not be including some other detail to this. As posted, `Form["sel1"]` has either "1" or "2", depending on what was selected.

Comment: I checked the code approx 201442 times. And still wasn't able to see the typo... It was just a letter missing. Feeling a bit stupid right now. Thanks for your help. Will delete the question in a few minutes

Comment: My question had nothing to do with the real problem. It was just a typo. This Question (in combination with the answers) would lead others into the complete wrong direction. That's why it should be deleted.

Answer (score 3):

The reason for that is because there is no value. No value will return null. The issue is with your HTML markup

```
<select name="sel1"><option>one</option><option>two</option></select>
```

Should be

```
<select name="sel1"><option value="one">one</option><option value="two">two</option></select>
```

Comment: Sorry. Forgot that on this post, but not in the real-world-code. Updated my question